# AWS s3 getIterator ListObjects after moving to another server producing an error

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ses, aws-php-sdk

I have a script on my current server that grabs objects in an s3 bucket which are emails coming in from an SES setup I have and loops through them. It currently works just fine and does its job.

I am creating a new Production server which is an exact duplicate of this current server. The only difference is that this new server will be accessed from a subdomain as opposed to the current server that is accessed from `www` AND the IP address is changing.

On the new Production server, my script is breaking at this point.

```
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => $bucketName));
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why it is breaking. I checked my S3CLient results and it appears to be working just fine. I can do a `print_r` and I can view the results and I do not see any errors.

```
try {
// Instantiate the client.
    $s3 = new S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => 'us-west-2',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => '*******************',
            'secret' => '***********************************',
        ],
    ]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

I thought maybe this has to do with some domain verification issue that SES requires but to me it does not seem to be related since the error is being caused from the `s3` side.

I went through my `IAM` roles and I could not see anything in there that would be domain-specific.

Is there some kind of permissions issue with the s3 bucket that is domain or IP specific? I set this up ages ago so I can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I figured it out. On my current server, I was using the AWS SDK for PHP from downloading the folder and not installing it with composer. On my new server, I installed the SDK through composer and removed and `require` I had pointed to the old folder SDK and it works now.